# errors(:base) << message leads undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I am trying to integrate ActiveMerchant into my website using Rails 3.2. Currently I have code to do general validation on a credit card using the ActiveMerchant "valid" function, which returns some error message if the card i not valid. If there are errors then I would like to add them to errors and re-render the view to display the view with the errors. Below is the code in my controller.

**First I create a credit card**

```
def credit_card
    first_name = User.find(user_id).first_name
    last_name = User.find(user_id).last_name
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :brand              => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expiration.month,
      :year               => card_expiration.year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )
  end
```

**Next I validate the card and try to add errors returned to the base errors for views**

```
# Active Merchant Credit Card validation

def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid?
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
       errors[:base] << message
      end
    end
end
```

**Finally I call valid_card on the create**

```
validate :validate_card, :on => :create
```

**However I am getting the error below**

> NoMethodError in Orders#create
>
> Showing app/views/orders/_form.html.erb where line #18 raised:
>
> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line
>
> ## 18):
>
> 15:  16:    17:     <%= f.label :print_dimension
> %>
>  18:     <%= f.collection_select :print_dimension_id,
> @print_dimensions, :id, :dimension %> 19:    20:    21:     <%= f.label :delivery_option_id %>

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your `@print_dimensions` is `nil` and part of the `collection_select` code is that it calls `map` on the enumerable object you are supposed to pass there.

I cannot tell why it's nil from the provided code - there is no mention of print_dimensions. But my guess is that you initialize this variable somewhere in the `#new` action but not in the "fail" part of the `#create` action. But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to the fact that my collection_select data was Nil. Essentially when I try to do a New action and it fails it then gets passed to Create, which tries to re-render the New page, but no longer has the collection_select data.

Here is a link to a answer that is similar to mine - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971138/rails-3-undefined-method-map-for-nilnilclass-for-my-own-validation)